# Moving object suddenly veers off a linear direction at constant speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

Not sure how to solve this problem.  I have an running humanoid moving in a straight line at at constant velocity on a flat plane.  Somewhere at z = 1750 of the humanoid's location, it suddenly veers off to the right.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  This does not happen every time, so I think this may be a Unity bug.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a minimal repeatable code sample which you can share? Sometimes it helps to see some code.Other pointers for asking great questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does it have a rigidbody attached? If so, turn off gravity for the rigidbody and see if it goes away. It could be being effected by gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt response, Jamie and Brandon.  The issue was with the branch of a terrain palm tree that was intersecting the plane. The branch was obscured from view by the plane.  I deleted the tree and my problem was solved.